# Part 2 of the Fundamental Theory of Calculus

Tags: calculus

I am not sure I understand the second part of the FMT. From what I understand, it just states that $F'(x)=f(x)$ where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. This makes sense to me, but when asked to solve for the area under the curve $5t^2-5t$ from $2$ to $x$, I just don't see how it applies.

I tried using the first part of FMT (I have no problem with that) and stating that is was equal to $F(x)-F(2)$, which would be $5x^2-5x-10$, but that was rejected by the computer. I have a whole host of other problems like this one, so I really need to understand how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: You are right that the answer is $F(x) - F(2)$, but you are not right that $F(x) - F(2)$ is equal to $5x^2 - 5x - 10$.  What is $F$ and what is $f$?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are given $F'(t) = f(t) = 5t^2-5t$, NOT $F(t)$. You need to find the antiderivative of $f(t)$, which is $F(t)$, and then you can use that function to find $F(x) - F(2)$